# Padding in openssl AES_cbc_encrypt

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

I was searching for implementations of AES, and i read that the OPENSSL have the best implementations, so i took a code from openssl, aes 128 cbc, and use it in my project, because i don't want to link whole library for the sake of one method. However it seems there is no padding implementation in:

`AES_cbc_encrypt`

So is padding a basically a size that is added to make data the multiplicity of key size?

So if i have following, key size is 128 bit - 16 byte

```
char dataToEncrypt[73];

BOOL bResult = ReadFile(hDataFile, dataToEncrypt, 73, &bRead, 0);
```

I need to calculate how much zeros i need to add:

So if: `73 % 16 != 0`
i need to calculate: `73 / 16 = 4`, 
then add one block: `4 + 1 = 5`, size in bytes would be `16 * 5 = 80`, 
add `80 - 73 = 7`, `7` zero bytes to the end of my buffer `dataToEncrypt`, and encrypt as

`AES_cbc_encrypt(dataToEncrypt, encrypted, 80, &dk, iv, AES_DECRYPT);`

Is this what evp version of aes is suppose to do?

Comment: You should *not* use `AES_encrypt` and friends. That's a software-only implementation, so you will not enjoy hardware support, like AES-NI. You should be using `EVP_*` functions. See [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. In fact, you should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Zero-Padding is irreversible (you can't tell how many bytes are data and how many bytes were added for padding). Have a look at different padding schemes (f.ex. on Wikipedia)

Comment: @jww i could just do it, but i was looking for tiny implementation of only aes-128,  but it seems only solution is to link whole openssl library

Comment: *"... because i don't want to link whole library for the sake of one method ..."* - Most unused code is usually removed by the linker. You can compile with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and link with `-Wl,--gc-sections` to aggressively remove unused code and data.